# C++11 shared_ptr and pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, shared-ptr

I have a library with APIs using `std::shared_ptr` as arguments.

I would like to use these APIs together with pthreads.

What I'm doing is: getting a raw pointer from the shared_ptr, in order to pass it to the pthread.
Create a new shared_ptr from the raw one and call my API from another thread.
However I get a `double free or corruption` error when converting the raw pointer back to a shared one.

This is my code

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>

void* print_task(void* ptr) 
{
    int* val_raw = static_cast<int*>(ptr);
    std::shared_ptr<int> val(val_raw);

    // CALL MY API WHICH TAKES A SHARED_PTR AS ARGUMENT
    std::cout<<"thread job done \n";
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

   pthread_t thread;

   std::shared_ptr<int> val = std::make_shared<int>(10);
   pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &print_task, static_cast<void *>(val.get()));

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

   return 0;
}
```

I guess that I'm doing something wrong with all the conversions from shared to raw pointer, because the same code using std::threads (where I can pass directly a shared_ptr) works.
However I need to set thread priorities, thus I'm trying to do this with pthreads.

Do you know how to change my code in order to be able to pass a shared pointer and use it inside a pthread?

Comment: Why not use C++ threads? Last time I looked, they exposed the underlying thread handle just for the case that you needed to do something special that the common API doesn't support.

Comment: I need to specify the thread priority.
Moreover I am using pthreads in all the application and I can't change the thread implementation just for this single use case

Comment: Why don't you just pass a pointer to std::shared_ptr, then copy construct another one inside the thread?

Comment: *Because I need to set the priority of the threads* Have you tested your algorithm and/or processes and determined that setting thread priorities actually does something both measurable and important?  Or are you just assuming that you need to set thread priorities without actual testing?

Comment: If you're using anything but Windows ( and probably there too; I just never looked) you can set priority of a C++11 and later thread with the `native_handle()` member function as your thread id to the POSIX api.

Comment: Yes, this is just a toy example to illustrate what I need to do. In any case I can't use something which is not pthread

Comment: The question could be reduced to "How do I pass a shared_ptr through a void pointer?" The threads are a red herring, partially.

Comment: "when converting the raw pointer back to a shared one." - you can't do that.   You end up with two SEPARATE shared_ptr's - each with their own reference count and each of which go to 0 and try to delete the object.

Comment: Having told you how you can change priority of a pthread hosted in a `std::thread` , was there some other *specific* reason (apart from "I just don't want to") why you can't use C++11 threading ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for making me notice that `std::thread` allows to set priority, but my question is about how to solve a problem with pthreads. 
If you confirm me that this can't be done with pthreads I'm fine

Comment: `CALL MY API WHICH TAKES A SHARED_PTR AS ARGUMENT` Can you post an example api?

Comment: @KamilCuk This is one of the API that I will call from the thread http://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/namespacerclcpp.html#a21e13577f5bcc5992de1d7dd08d8652b

Comment: Why are you creating a `shared_ptr` in `main`? You aren't passing a `shared_ptr` to the thread, and you don't want to manage the object's lifetime in `main`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are right, but outside this toy example I would need a reference to the object also in the main thread.

Comment: @alsora For that to work, you need to pass the `shared_ptr` to the thread, not the underlying object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, the problem is passing a shared pointer through a raw void pointer, so I'll ignore the threading part for now:

```
// this is what we have and what we want to pass to the given function
shared_ptr<some_type> sptr;

// function to somehow pass the shared pointer to
void function(void* ptr);

// As always, when passing anything that doesn't fit into
// the raw pointer, we need to do dynamic allocation:
void* arg = new shared_ptr<some_type>(sptr);

// we can now pass this to the function as intended:
function(arg);

// Note that we give up ownership of the dynamically allocated
// shared pointer instance. Hence, the called function must
// release that object again (it takes ownership). The function
// therefore starts like this:
void function(void* ptr)
{
    // convert the typeless pointer to a typed pointer again
    shared_ptr<some_type>* psptr = static_cast<shared_ptr<some_type>*>(ptr);
    // move the content to a new, local instance
    shared_ptr<some_type> sptr = *psptr;
    // release the dynamically allocated shared pointer again
    delete psptr;
    /// ... code using sptr here ...
}
```

Now, while this is guaranteed to work, under some circumstances this may not be an optimal solution:

- Firstly, the ups and downs of the reference counter don't come for free, especially since that is done in a thread-safe, atomic way. Copying the shared pointer inside the function just to then delete the copied pointer can be avoided. Just create as empty instance and swap() it with the pointer to copy. Assuming swap() is specialized, which is a safe bet because it's an obvious optimization, that then boils down to swapping two raw pointers. This swap doesn't have to be thread-safe and is therefore much faster.
- Secondly, dynamic allocations are expensive. You could avoid this and the manual release by passing the address of the original object to the function, but then you would have to guarantee that the object is not touched while the function is still executing. Especially with threads, that requires taking extra care.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a tricky little conundrum to be honest. The problem you are having is that by passing the raw pointer to your thread function you end up with two *independant* shared pointers managing the same object *instead of* two *connected* shared pointers *sharing* ownership.

Consequently *both* shared pointers try to delete it.

You **also** have a nasty *lifetime problem* to avoid if you pass a pointer to the shared pointer itself because you can not guarantee the shared pointer will not go out of scope before the new thread has copied it.

I get round that by passing a **second** dynamically allocated `std::shared_ptr` created from the original `std::shared_ptr` which guarantees the shared pointer's control block will live until the new thread tries to copy it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>

void* print_task(void* ptr)
{
    // obtain the shared pointer from the dynamically created one guarantees
    // we will bee accessing a living control block preventing an
    // end-of-lifetime catastrophe
    std::shared_ptr<int> val = *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>*>(ptr);

    // DON'T FORGET TO DELETE THIS!!!
    // We had to allocate this dynamically to guarantee it lived until after
    // it was used.
    delete static_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>*>(ptr);

    // CALL MY API WHICH TAKES A SHARED_PTR AS ARGUMENT
    std::cout << "thread job done \n";

    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;

    // create the shared resource. This MAY go out of scope
    // before the new thread copies it (however unlikely you
    // think that is).
    std::shared_ptr<int> val = std::make_shared<int>(10);

    // So instead of sending the shared pointer we create a NEW std::shared_ptr
    // which will keep the shared pointer's control block alive even if the original
    // shared pointer goes out of scope.
    pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &print_task,
        static_cast<void*>(new std::shared_ptr<int>(val)));

    // Do other time consuming thread stuff here.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));


    // Tidy up.
    void* ret = nullptr;
    pthread_join(thread, &ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you now have a `new`/`delete` pair here but you still gain in passing the shared ownership round between threads.

I suppose you can even get rid of that `delete` by adopting the passed in raw pointer by a *temporary* `std::unique_ptr`.

```
void* print_task(void* ptr)
{
    // obtain the shared pointer from the dynamically created one guarantees
    // we will bee accessing a living control block preventing an
    // end-of-lifetime catastrophe
    std::shared_ptr<int> val = *std::unique_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>>(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>*>(ptr));

    // CALL MY API WHICH TAKES A SHARED_PTR AS ARGUMENT
    std::cout << "thread job done \n";

    return nullptr;
}
```